# Changing System Language Using .Net Framework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, powershell

I am currently trying to change the System language using C#. I am building a Windows Desktop Application to allow the user to select the language available in their language list. (Powershell command: Get-WinUserLanguageList). Is it possible to be able to call the language list using C# or would I need to execute powershell commands (Set-WinUserLanguageList)

Comment: Is this what you're after? `https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/EnumSystemLocales.html` If so let me know I'll post as an answer.

Comment: Is this the only way to go about it? I'm assuming there are no libraries that can execute at an OS level unless I automate my powershell scripts.

Comment: There are probably other ways, but that site is a great reference to windows classes. I just looked that up and that's what I found so that's where I'd start.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set-WinSystemLocale` and `Set-WinUserLanguageList`:

```
Set-WinSystemLocale en-US
Set-WinUserLanguageList en-US
```

Do note that this won't install any missing language packs, so they either need to be installed from `Control Panel`, or you can use handy PowerShell to do that for you too:

```
# Check installed languages
$availableLanguages = ( Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem ).MUILanguages

# Install a new language (-PackagePath could also be on a UNC path as well)
# You will have to reboot after this for the language to become available
Add-WindowsPackage -Online -PackagePath C:\path\to\LanguagePack\lp_blah.cab
```

In order to obtain a new language pack cab file, see [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-language-packs-to-windows#get-languages) for more information. There should also be additional language packs available on your Windows' setup media.